# pure magento - can not log in and register on localhost

Tags: magento2

I moved my online store and full database to localhost, everything works fine but I can not log in and set up a new account.

**So I installed a second, clean magento. Unfortunately, the problem is still the same even on pure magento. What to do ?**

When I try log in, the page only refreshes and does not go to the account panel.

Comment: Can you provide your localhost setup? How are you handling cookies? What do your server (in your case localhost server) PHP logs look like?

Comment: Using virtual host instead of localhost domain.

Comment: Could you please mention magento version and system specification?

Comment: Use your local IP address instead of accessing it like http://localhost/your-project. This is a known issue with browsers like chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your localhost url with `http://127.0.0.1/{magento2}` because in chrome with localhost is not supported and you can directly change code in database from `core_config_data` table.

Replace

**`web/unsecure/base_url`** with `http://127.0.0.1/{magento2}/`

and

**`web/secure/base_url`** with `http://127.0.0.1/{magento2}/`

**clear cache and remove var folder from root.**